# undefined root error when using routerLinkeActive in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularJS 2 to create a SPA application. I'm trying to add a class to the button for the active path. According to the [Angular 2's router documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) I should use the `RouterLinkActive` directive to add a class. However when I do so I get `Cannot read property 'root' of undefined` error. The app works perfectly if I remove the `routerLinkActive="active"` from the template.

Router code:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {path : '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path : 'home', component : HomeComponent}
    {path : 'item', component : ItemListComponent}
    {path : 'item/:id', component : ItemComponent},
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

HTML template code:

```
<button [routerLink]="['home']" class="btn btn-block" routerLinkActive="active">Home</button>
<button [routerLink]="['item']" class="btn btn-block">Items</button>
```

Component Code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  precompile: [HomeComponent, ItemListComponent],
  templateUrl: `app/templates/main-page.template.html`
})
export class HomePageComponent { }
```

Error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in app/templates/main-page.template.html:15:8
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
```

What is the root propery and where should I define it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The undefined root error is a bug in the current release of angular2 (2.0.0-rc.4) that doesn't allow routeLink to be used with non-anchor tags if routerLinkActive is present. The issue seems fixed in master (see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9755)

For the current release you would need to wrap the button around an anchor tag. It should look something like this:

```
<a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">
    <button class="btn btn-block" >Home</button>
</a>

<a routerLink="/item">
    <button class="btn btn-block">Items</button> 
</a>
```

Comment: @Didn't know this! Completed my answear!

Answer (score 2):

The `routeLink` at your button element is wrong. Should look like here:

```
<button [routerLink]="home" class="btn btn-block" routerLinkActive="active">Home</button>
```

Reference: [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html)

Comment: I changed the button code to the one you mentioned. However I now I get the following error parser now:
`EXCEPTION: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token / at column 1 in [/home] in HomeComponent@15:16 ("<button [ERROR ->][routerLink]="/home" class="btn btn-block" routerLinkActive="active" >Home</button>")`

Comment: @FarshadMomtaz because your route is only 'home', not '/home', I miss typed it!

Comment: Removing the slash would result in the same undefined root error. However, if I remove the `routerLinkActive="active"` from the button the page would load but clicking on the button would result in the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`